# Set dark background after show bubble layout - android

Tags: android

i want show custom bubble view (`custom layout`) after click on the button. i write this code and show carefully but when show bubble view i want to be a little dark background such as show dialog! 
How to create this ? can you help me or send me true code? 
Tnx all dears <3

Comment: set that custom view in Dialog with custom layout (your bubble) and set transparent background on Window and set dimAmount attributes, set flags for your dialog in activity activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

Comment: @n.m. : can you send me true code? please :( i need this :(